# Error 1064 (42000)

Tags: python, mysql

Hola tengo el siguiente error, lo raro es que en una consulta mysql workbench esto resulta, pero en python no es asi y me salta el siguiente error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.nombreCargo, area.nombreArea, usuario.usuario, usuario.contrasenia 
        ...' at line 2
```

pero cuando realizo esta consulta en python me salta este error.

```
SELECT  trabajador.rut, trabajador.nombre, trabajador.apellido, 
trabajador.correo, trabajador.telefono
cargo.nombreCargo, area.nombreArea, usuario.usuario, usuario.contrasenia
FROM trabajador INNER JOIN area ON area.idArea = trabajador.idArea 
INNER JOIN cargo ON cargo.idCargo = trabajador.idCargo 
INNER JOIN usuario ON usuario.idUsuario = trabajador.idUsuario;
```

Y este es el codigo en python

```
def consulta_trabajador(self):
    cur = self.cnn.cursor()
    sql = """SELECT  t.idTrabajador, t.rut, t.nombre, t.apellido, 
            t.correo, t.telefono 
            c.nombreCargo, a.nombreArea, u.usuario, u.contrasenia 
            FROM trabajador t INNER JOIN area  a ON a.idArea = t.idArea  
            INNER JOIN cargo c ON c.idCargo = t.idCargo  
            INNER JOIN usuario u ON u.idUsuario = t.idUsuario"""
    cur.execute(sql)
    datos = cur.fetchall() 
    cur.close()    
    return datos
```

La verdad no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta una coma:

```
SELECT  trabajador.rut, trabajador.nombre, trabajador.apellido, 
trabajador.correo, trabajador.telefono, <---AQUI
cargo.nombreCargo, area.nombreArea, usuario.usuario, usuario.contrasenia
FROM trabajador INNER JOIN area ON area.idArea = trabajador.idArea 
INNER JOIN cargo ON cargo.idCargo = trabajador.idCargo 
INNER JOIN usuario ON usuario.idUsuario = trabajador.idUsuario;
```

Según tu respuesta actualizada te indico los dos problemas que puedes tener:

1. Estás apuntando a otra base de datos, si es la misma base de datos debe devolverte la misma información, intenta depurar la consulta que realizas en python imprimiendo el resultado al terminal, con un print.
2. Si el print del resultado te devuelve los datos, cuando lo estás pintando no tienes los nombres de las columnas escritos correctamente.

Comment: Gracias por responder, claramente era la coma, pero ahora tengo otro problema. Resulta que en mysql workbench me muestra todos los datos de las demas tablas, pero en python solo me muestra los datos del trabajador...sabras tu porque?

Comment: no entiendo bien la pregunta, el select debe darte la información de lo que selecciones, si en los campos del select no tienes indicado algún campo no lo mostrarás en Python, Mysql Workbench realiza una consulta de todos los campos de todas las tablas, por eso las ves.

Answer (score 0):

La [respuesta](/a/573945) de [techdobycon](/users/313943) fue sencilla y clara. Di con el resultado esperado y ahora obtengo los datos que deseo ver.

El error era el siguiente: Tenía una función que leía la bbdd incorrecta, por eso me daba el del título de esta pregunta (Error 1064 (42000)). Como no me daba los resultados esperados y me producía el error, para saber qué funcionaba y qué no, reduje el número de listas a mostrar, por lo que cuando ya solucionado el problema me seguía mostrando los mismos datos. Corregido el error, me mostró todos los datos al igual que en mysql workbench...

Muestro la tabla que tenía el error:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.cnn = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root", 
        passwd="",
        database="caras" #debia ser resgitroes
    )

def __init__(self):
    self.cnn = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root", 
        passwd="",
        database="registroes" #Corregido
    )
```

Luego de eso corregí la función que mostraba los datos, en este caso estoy usando tkinter.

```
def llenarDatos(self):
    datos = self.persona.consulta_trabajador()
    for row in datos: 
        print(row)   <-- aqui depuraba el codigo x'DD
        self.grid.insert("", END, text=row[0], values=(row[1], row[2], row[3], 
        row[4], row[5], row[2]))     <--- el error
    if len(self.grid.get_children()) > 0:
        self.grid.selection_set(self.grid.get_children()[0])
```

luego lo corregí

```
def llenarDatos(self):
    datos = self.persona.consulta_trabajador()
    for row in datos: 
        print(row)   
        self.grid.insert("", END, text=row[0], values=(row[1], row[2], row[3], 
        row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9]))   <--corregido  
    if len(self.grid.get_children()) > 0:
        self.grid.selection_set(self.grid.get_children()[0])
```

Así quedó la tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y así me mostró los datos el print

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]